# How to compute the determinant of this block matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices, schur-complement

$$M = \left[\begin{matrix} -C & -A \\ A^\top & 0
\end{matrix} \right]$$
I found a paper using $\det(M) = \det(A^\top C^{-1}A)$ but don't know how to prove this.

Comment: Have you seen the sketch in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices)?

Comment: That determinant is missing a factor, isn't it?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The paper doesn't have any factor, although it's used only to show non-singularity.

Comment: *Hint*:  use the computation of determinants by blocks.

Comment: He did omit a factor. Just found he fixed this in his thesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing Gaussian elimination,

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm A^\top \mathrm C^{-1} & \mathrm I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} - \mathrm C & -\mathrm A \\ \mathrm A^\top & \mathrm O \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} - \mathrm C & -\mathrm A \\ \mathrm O & -\mathrm A^\top \mathrm C^{-1} \mathrm A \end{bmatrix}$$

Note that the determinant of a block triangular matrix is the product of the determinants of the diagonal blocks.